# How to save changes to firebase document if user closes window or tab

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, polymer-2.x

*Context:* I have a use case where in the components used is firebase realtime database in Polymer 2.x. I have a function that does transformations on certain user activity with the firebase realtime object. I used polymerfire webcomponent.

*What I want is:* on user closes tab or window, save the data into firebase realtime database and then close the window.

*Result:* I used on beforeunload of window in the script of the polymer element. But not able to fire a method inside polymer element that triggers storage of the data in realtime db.

*What I am looking for:*
1. A way to initiate the element public function from script of an element.
Or
2. a better way to implement on window/tab close save the data

Thanks.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<dom-module id="t-page">
<template is="dom-bind">
....
</template>
<script>
var myEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
var chkevent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' :
  'beforeunload'; /// make IE7, IE8 compitable

myEvent(chkevent, async function (e) { // For >=IE7, Chrome, Firefox
  var confirmationMessage = 'Are you sure to leave the page?'; // a space
  (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;
  setTimeout(async () => {
    document.getElementById('trello-page').onCloseWindow();
  }, 2500);
  return confirmationMessage;
});

/**
 * @polymer
 * @extends HTMLElement
 */
class TPage extends Polymer.Element {

  static get is() {
    return 't-page';
  }

 ... some properties ....{ colUpdateArr{...}}

 async onCloseWindow() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.colUpdateArr.length; i += 2) {
      var toCol = this.colUpdateArr[i];
      var fromCol = this.colUpdateArr[i + 1];
      await this.$.query.ref.child(toCol.$key).child('tasks').set(toCol.tasks);
      await this.$.query.ref.child(fromCol.$key).child('tasks').set(fromCol.tasks);
    }
  }

  } //end Polymer.Element

      window.customElements.define(TPage.is, TPage);
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Comment: Did you consider saving the data when the user changes it? That way you'd have nothing to do when they choose to close the page.

Comment: I tried that ... I am using Sortablejs and it has some challenges if the record is removed from DB. I have raised a stackoverflow question too. I found a workaround for Sortablejs and Firebase polymerfire to work using dummy object that I wish to sync with firebase db. Not the best solution but it worked with constraints which is the above ticket. I update the db on view change but not able to fire the method in on beforeunload event.

Comment: Not sure about how (or if) polymerfire exposes it, but I think you're looking for the firebase.database.onDisconnect function: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.OnDisconnect#update